# (Binomal Distribution) With n = 20, p = 0.2, calculate the probability that 2X >4 (Homework)

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

This is a homework question. The scenario is as follows:
A dishwasher can accommodate 20 plates in one loading. With every loading, there is a 20% chance that 1 plate will not be cleaned properly. With X representing the number of plates that are not cleaned properly, find P(2X > 4).
n = 20, p = 0.2

I have no idea how to find P(2X > 4). Any hints or thoughts on this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$2X > 4$ is the same as $X > 2$. Now think about relationship between $P(X > x)$ and $P(X \leq x)$.

Comment: Oh. I didnt think of that property. I'll work on that. Thanks for your help. @asifzuba